# How can vue3+Element-plus display the data returned by the backend as a table?

Tags: vue.js

[The way you want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKaxW.png)
[Format of data received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQTVQ.png)
I have received data from the backend as shown in the image above, which includes a lot of detailed information, but I only need to display a portion of it, and I don't know how to process the data to generate a table for displaying the data. I have generated five small display boxes by getting data.location, and v-for, but I don't know how to handle the rest of the data and display it?